# which event is called at last before redirecting to another page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms

My scenario is like this ...
I am maintaining a session value consider as **session["activewindow"]** which i need to set to false before redirect to another page, and when it is redirected to new page on page load event i am again setting **session["activewindow"]** to true, but if **session["activewindow"] is already true then i am throwing user back to login page**. If i am redirecting from serverside using Response.Redirect then it is working fine, but i am having some anchor tabs in html (page redirect using `<a href="WebForm4.aspx" > Click here </a>`)
from which also page can be redirected.

So i want to make Session["activewindow"] to false before redirecting .

Also i forgot to mention that in my application , the pages are redirected using dynamic menus , so i want to achieve in this .

In short my aim is to allow user to open only one tab in same browser.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinkButton` and set session on click event of this button and also write redirect code.

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can't do that using a normal HTML anchor tag cause you will need a server side event where you can set the session and redirect to another page. As correctly pointed in another answer you can use a serverside control like LinkButton for this purpose.

BTW, from your post looks like you trying to do something similar to `Forms Authentication`. In such case, why you are trying to build something your own rather you should use built-in forms authentication feature.

Comment: i have just updated my question, please check if you can help it out.